# Redirect another domain to folder without url changing htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a htaccess redirect (without url change) to a folder where my site is. Recently i got a new domain name, but i can't get the htaccess code working on that domain.

main domain: www.test.com
folder of site: /drupal

this is the htaccess code i use (so users go to www.test.com and see the /drupal conten)

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.test.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ drupal/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/drupal%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* drupal/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* drupal/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/drupal/$ http://www.test.com/
```

Now, i have a new domain www.secondtest.com on that server, which content stands on /drupal2 but whenever i type www.secondtest.com into my browser he redirects me to www.test.com .

Is there a way to modify the htaccess like so?

```
www.test.com (go's invisible to folder) --> www.test.com/drupal 
www.secondtest.com (go's invisible to folder) --> www.test.com/drupal2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an another RewriteCond to check the domain :

```
# Redirection if not www.test.com nor www.secondtest.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.secondtest\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.test.com/ [L,R=301]

# redirection to drupal folder if test.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* drupal/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]

# redirection to drupal2 folder if secondtest.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.secondtest\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* drupal2/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```